# Dynamics CRM 2016 Changing state attributes is not allowed in create stage 20 plugins

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I am using Dynamics CRM 2016 Sandbox Org. I am getting this error when setting statecode and status code values in pre-operation event pipeline. "Changing state attributes is not allowed in create stage 20 plugins."

I cannot update my plugin to be on post operation due to some business requirements. Its working fine in CRM 2015,2013.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom entity

Comment: Do you set the state/status by just changing the attributes?

Comment: I am setting like this entity["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(1)

Comment: Were you actually able to do that in CRM 2015/2013? I'm not really challenging you on this since I don't Think I've had to create a record with status X but rather update them to status X, and the you have to use the SetStatusRequest. Just out of curiosity, what is the business reuqirement that prevents you from updating the created object in post stage with a setstatusrequest?

Comment: Yes its working fine in CRM 2013/2015 but its not working in CRM 2016 sandbox org.

Answer (score 0):

To set the state and status on Pre-Create event you can use the code below. I've tested this on SalesOrder entity on CRM 2015 in the **Pre-Validation** stage. It sets the sales order status directly to pending when a new order is created.

You must make sure you are setting a correct combination of state and status values.

```
                Int32 statusVal = 2;
                Int32 stateVal = 0;

                if (((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Contains("statuscode"))
                {
                    ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"])["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(statusVal);
                }
                else {
                    ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Attributes.Add("statuscode", new OptionSetValue(statusVal));
                }

                if (((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Contains("statecode"))
                {
                    ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"])["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue(stateVal);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]).Attributes.Add("statecode", new OptionSetValue(stateVal));
                }
```

...

If you would like to use Post Create event where you have the entity id you can try using **SetStateRequest**.

Make sure you have a valid combination of state and status values.

```
public static void SetStatusOfObject(IOrganizationService service, string entityName, Guid entityId, int state, int status)
    {
        SetStateRequest updateStatus = new SetStateRequest();
        updateStatus.EntityMoniker = new EntityReference(entityName, entityId);
        updateStatus.State = new OptionSetValue(state);
        updateStatus.Status = new OptionSetValue(status);
        service.Execute(updateStatus);
    }
```

Comment: In pre-create you don't have an entityId and I think in new crm versions you can do this with an update.

Comment: You are correct in pre-create this will not work, thanks for the correction. i will give a shot on some things on pre-create.

Comment: One more thing, the Constains should be for the Target, not for the state or status because you are not using the status values, you are only setting the data :). `if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") & context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)`

Comment: The check you are mentioning is, for checking if the plugin context contains the target entity object being updated, which i assume is already been done in the plugin. 

The checks i have in the code are related to if the target Entity object has the statuscode and statecode attributes. It is not the same thing.

Comment: What I mean is that checks are not necessary because if I have an Entity, i can set the state and status using `entity["state"] = value` and `entity["status"] = value` you don't need to ask for the contains of state or status because that's in the end a DataCollection.

Comment: Yes, i agree but prefer to add checks for that. Still, i cannot test this on 2016, as i do not have access to an organization like that.

Comment: You should not use SetStateRequest because it is deprecated. You should use a regular Update request in post-operation stage.

Comment: Yes, the request seems to be deprecated in version 2016, this answer refers to CRM 2015 only,